# Creating buttons with an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, uibutton

I have 44 buttons that I am adding to a scrollview and I was trying to use a series of arrays to do so.  I have arrays for the name strings of the filenames, for the Y sizes of the pics (all x's are the same) and a few others.

The code that I have in my viewDidLoad that runs the method is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++) {
    [self makeLabelsAndButtons:i];
}
```

And the method makeLabelsAndButtons is here:

```
-(void)makeLabelsAndButtons:(NSInteger *)indexPath{
NSString *nameString = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath];
NSString *picString = [picArray objectAtIndex:indexPath];
NSInteger picNumb = [[numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath] integerValue];
NSInteger picXnum = [[picXCoords objectAtIndex:indexPath] integerValue];

Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(presPressed:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
Button.frame = CGRectMake(160.0, 240.0, 220.0, picNumb);
Button.center = CGPointMake(picXnum, 200.0);
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:picString] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[ScrollView addSubview:Button];
[ScrollView insertSubview:Button atIndex:1];

NSLog(@"name: %@, pic:%@, picY:%i", nameString, picString, picNumb);

}
```

The buttons are not being added, but I get no errors. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: This is how I'm initializing my scrollview

```
ScrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
ScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
ScrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
ScrollView.bounces = YES;
ScrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:ScrollView];
[self.view insertSubview:ScrollView atIndex:1];
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(20000,480);
```

Via a system of NSLogs I've determined that the buttons aren't being added to the view and I don't know why.

Comment: its a UIButton defined in my header, and a nonatomic property

Comment: ok. Now, 2 questions - are this buttons have normal frames ? i mean normal height? and if you add Button.backgroundcolor = [UIColor redColor] for example, you still dont see them?

Comment: the buttons all have different heights, thats why I have the heights stored in an array that I run through to create the buttons. I tried the background color, still didn't see them, the background color didn't even show

Comment: ok. lets move on - does the scrollView have the correct frame? the correct contentSize? is it suitable to the frames of the buttons?

Comment: its large enough to hold all the frames of the buttons yes

Comment: I copied you code, and it worked fine for me. You didn't specify everything, so I made some assumptions, so maybe I'm doing something slightly different. Where do you initialize the scroll view? How are you declaring ScrollView and Button (those really should start with lowercase letters)?

Comment: My scrollview is being initialized as seen above in my answer, and the button is just declared as a UIButton in my .h file

Answer (score 0):

Change Your code according to following..... it may work

```
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:picString] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Replace above with

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picString" ofType:@"png"];
[Button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: then Problem could be in scrollView frame in which you are adding buttons.Check Whether scrollview's frame is correct.

Comment: UIScrollView has to be initialized and added to superview with some frame value as well as contentSize... is Your ScrollView Visible?  You are not able to see buttons but are you able to see ScrollView?

Comment: I've updated the post with how Im initializing the scrollview

Comment: @tyler53 makeLabelsAndButtons:(NSInteger *)indexPath, this is just a typo rite, no pointer is needed for NSInteger. makeLabelsAndButtons:(NSInteger)indexPath

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have two properties `Button` and `ScrollView` declared on your controller.

- Rename the property `ScrollView` to `scrollView` for readability.

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
  ```
- Delete the property `Button` because you don't need it.
- Update your code:

  ```
  Button *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(presPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(160.0, 240.0, 220.0, picNumb);
  button.center = CGPointMake(picXnum, 200.0);
  [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:picString] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
  ```

You don't need to both add the subview and insert it.

It might be that you weren't allocating `ScrollView` and sending messages to nil objects will not give you an error. You need to confirm that self.scrollView is not nil, if it is, then check that it is wired up properly in your view.

Comment: self.scrollview is not nil, there are labels being added in another method that work just fine.  also, this solution didn't work :/

Comment: What is the value of picXnum the first time your `makeLabelsAndButtons:` method is called. If that puts the center of the button outside the frame of the scrollView then you will not see them.

Comment: Also, when you are initializing your ScrollView you shouldn't be adding and inserting it into the view.

Comment: Ok, that does look right, I would also check that `[UIImage imageNamed:picString]` isn't returning nil.

Comment: its not, I have an NSLog checking all of the variables

Comment: You might try looping through all ScrollView.subviews, sometime after you finish making all your calls to `makeLabelsAndButtons:`, and confirming that there are actually button objects there.

Comment: What do you mean by looping through all the ScrollView.subviews?

Comment: `for (UIView *subview in ScrollView.subviews) NSLog(@"%@", subview);` to test if the views are being added. It will help you debug. If they are there, then you can assume that they are positioned incorrectly or not visible for some other reason. If they are not there then they are not being added correctly.

Comment: Then there are no subviews. You can NSLog the count of the array to confirm. The problem is that they are not being added.

Comment: So then what would I do to make them add correctly, I've updated my question at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137323/creating-buttons-by-looping-through-an-array/16137485#16137485

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your scrollView is horizontally scrollable.

You can try

```
-(void)addButtonsToScrollView
{
    //X Offset for button seperation 
    CGFloat xOffset = 10.0f;

    NSUInteger buttonCount = 0;
    //In each iteration buttonFrame would be adjusted to next buttonFrame
    //This would be used to find the contentSize of scrollView
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 240.0, 220.0, 40.0f);
    while (buttonCount<44)
    {
        NSString *nameString = nameArray[buttonCount];
        NSString *picString = picArray[buttonCount];

        CGFloat picNumb = [numbers[buttonCount] floatValue];
        CGFloat picXnum = [picXCoords[buttonCount] floatValue];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(presPressed:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        buttonFrame.origin.y = (scrollView.frame.size.height - picNumb)/2;
        buttonFrame.size.height = picNumb;
        button.frame = buttonFrame;

        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:picString]
                          forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitle:nameString
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [scrollView addSubview:button];

        buttonFrame.origin.x += buttonFrame.size.width+xOffset;
        buttonCount++;

    }

    CGSize contentSize = scrollView.frame.size;
    contentSize.width = buttonFrame.origin.x;
    scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;

}
```

Comment: @tyler53 Height of buttons are variable. Do you want to center the button in its container(scrollView)?

Comment: I've updated the post with how Im initializing the scrollview

Comment: still nothing, and I know the scrollview is being intialized because I have labels that scroll and work just fine

Comment: it seems like the buttons aren't being added, I just can't understand why

Comment: @tyler53 Can you share your source code, relevant to your issue?